# Blender 2.81 crashes when trying to save a new file

Tags: blend-files, error, path

I have an issue in Blender 2.81 in which it crashes whenever I try to open a file, save a new file, or try to edit the file paths in preferences, however, I can still drag and drop a file to open it and press ctrl+s to save an already existing file. Also, autosave is working and saving in the tmp folder. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: Okay that shouldn't happen.  I have been using 2.81 since the early beta and haven't had any troubles.  I run on BunsenLabs which is also Debian-based so should behave roughly the same way.

Comment: This appears to be a bug related to the Mesa graphics driver reported in [T69669](https://developer.blender.org/T69669) and [T69461](https://developer.blender.org/T69461). The reports sound like Ubuntu may have backported a fix.

Comment: Ubuntu has now upgraded to Mesa 19.1.4 through their regular software updater.  Problem is resolved by Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, in case anyone else has the same problem, I fixed it with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates`